# Polynomial time algorithm for finding a maximal monotone subset

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, subsequences

**Input:**
Some fixed $k>1$, vectors $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb R^k$ for $1\le i\le n$.

**Output:**
A subset $I\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$ of maximal size such that
$(x_i-x_j)^T(y_i-y_j) \ge 0$ for all $i,j\in I$.

**Question:**
Can this be computed in polynomial time in $n$?

**Remarks:**

- For $k=1$ this is equivalent to the problem of finding a longest increasing subsequence. Indeed, assuming that $x_1<\dots<x_n$, we search for a longest increasing subsequence of $y_1,\dots,y_n$. Such a subsequence can be found in $O(n\log n)$.
- The problem is related to the notion of a *monotone operator* $F:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^k$. Monotonicity of $F$ means that $(x_1-x_2)^T(F(x_1)-F(x_2))\ge 0$ for all $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R^k$.
- The problem can be formulated as a search for a maximum clique in the graph $G=(V,E)$ with vertices $V=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and edges
  $E = \{(i,j) \;:\; (x_i-x_j)^T(y_i-y_j)\ge 0 \}$.
  The general clique problem is NP-complete.
  However, it might be possible to exploit the special structure of $E$ (as shown in the first remark, this is possible when $k=1$).

I would appreciate any hint or comment on this problem.

Comment: Do you want a *maximal* clique, or a *maximum* clique? In the former, we essentially cannot extend a clique to a bigger clique, which is easily found: choose an arbitrary vertex and add as many adjacent vertices such that you maintain a clique. Finding a *maximum* clique is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete because we are looking for the largest clique out of all possible cliques.

Comment: You are right, the wording of the remark was ambigous. I have now edited it to say "maximum" instead of "maximal". However, I think the problem statement was precise: We search a subst I "of maximal size".

Comment: Just a small comment: if $k$ can depend on $n$, then it's NP-hard, since we can build a reduction from maximum clique: $k = n^2$, and $i * n + j$-th coordinate is $0$ for all vertices except $i$ and $j$. If there is an edge between them, then the coordinate is $0$ for both; otherwise, it's $1$ fr one and $-1$ for another.

Comment: That's correct, I also thought about adding this as a further remark :-)
Maybe asking the following question can lead to some insights: Let's suppose $k=2$. Can all possible graphs (i. e. all possible sets $E$) be realized by choosing $x_i, y_i$ appropriately? If not, what are the obstructions?

Comment: If you want k to be fixed, traditionally it shouldn't be listed as an input. It should instead be a fixed parameter of the problem. I might remove it from your list of inputs for clarity.

Comment: Is it about *concordance* between two random variables?

Answer (score 0):

I stared at this a while now with $k=2$ and got nowhere.

- Let's take on $k=2$. To avoid confusion with x and y coordinates, I'll call the vectors $a_i, b_i$ instead.
- Lets define $D(i,j)=(a_j-a_i)^T(b_j-b_i) \ge 0$, and $R(i,j)$ to be the boolean relation which holds when $D(i,j)\ge0$.
- For $k=1$, R was a total ordering, which is what let us find increasing subsequences. For $k=2$, it's not even a partial ordering, which makes me think any solution will not resemble the $k=1$ case.

  - Take $x_1,x_2,x_3=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$; $y_1, y_2, y_3=(0,0), (-6, 1), (-5,-5)$
  - $V(1,2)=1$; $V(2,3)=1$; $V(1,3)=-10$

I'd suggest checking if this can be reduced to the longest common subsequence problem (I suspect no, because of the lack of ordering) or to/from some form of linear programming.

To nitpick here, coordinates should really be taken from $\mathbb Z$ bounded by some reasonable (say, polynomial) function for CS problems, not "$\mathbb R$". I suspect you can show it's NP-complete otherwise, say by reduction to the longest common subsequence problem, but in some way that's not really related to whatever your real problem is. That said, I didn't succeed at actually doing so.